# Oracle SQL query - Joining on Max()?

Tags: sql, oracle, join, nested

So, what I'm trying to achieve is to see if a customer sent us an email last week - and if so - see how many times the customer emailed us the previous 7 days before that.

Example:

> hithere@stackoverflow.com sent an email last week (thursday). So a sub-query should then look for that E-mail from last week's thursday -7 days and count how many.

See my below query, if I completely ignore the E join it works fine, but I can't seem to JOIN on MAX().

Is there any workaround for that?

```
SELECT 
D.LABEL,
B.EMAILADDRESS,
MAX(TRUNC(A.COMPLETEDATE)) AS LastCompleted,
COUNT(E.MESSAGEID) AS count

FROM KC_MESSAGE A

LEFT OUTER JOIN KC_EMAILADDRESS B ON A.SENDERID = B.EMAILADDRESSID
LEFT OUTER JOIN KC_FOLDER C ON A.QUEUEID = C.FOLDERID
LEFT OUTER JOIN KC_DEPARTMENT D ON C.DEPARTMENTID = D.DEPARTMENTID

LEFT OUTER JOIN KC_MESSAGE E ON E.SENDERID = A.SENDERID 
AND TRUNC(E.COMPLETEDAY) BETWEEN MAX(TRUNC(A.COMPLETEDATE))-7 AND MAX(TRUNC(A.COMPLETEDATE))

WHERE TRUNC(A.COMPLETEDATE) BETWEEN TRUNC(SYSDATE-10) AND TRUNC(SYSDATE-4)
AND A.COMPLETEEVENTID = 9 

GROUP BY D.LABEL, B.EMAILADDRESS
```

Comment: Not sure which table you want to join on which based on the max value.
This will require a subquery to extract the max value of the column in the other table.

Comment: I'd like to join KC_MESSAGE E on the A table (same table but with different parameters if that makes sense). Have tried doing a subquery but can't get it to work.

Comment: ok, and what is the column name?